Simple Document Listing Organization
Does anyone know of a simple program or widget for Linux that allows a user to create a graphical listing of recent documents edited in the environment by various programs, and allows the documents to be grouped by subject or other criteria?  This would make the user more productive by allowing the user to pickup working on a subject or group project by link to editor of a given doc.
I could find no listing anywhere of such a thing.  Document management software is overkill.
